# Is there any solution for getting local resources from remote javascript in IOS?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to import a local font file, jquery, etc. in remote web page or javascript, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                let gbvar = new Object();       //globalVariable
                gbvar.device = "ios";           //device 정보
                
                if(gbvar.device == "ios"){
                    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///IOSLOCALASSET/resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' ><\/script>");
                    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///IOSLOCALASSET/resources/js/jquery-ui.js' ><\/script>");
                }
</script>
```

I have already completed this through WebViewAssetLoader in Android, but I want to know how to do it in IOS.

Is anybody did this in IOS?

..........................

Comment: In general, web browsers have security restrictions that prevent JavaScript code from accessing local resources on the user's device, including files, folders, and other data. This is a security measure designed to protect users from malicious code that could potentially steal sensitive information or cause other harm.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Mushtaq. I mean, in the WebView. Is it impossible even with a webview?